# Big O of 2 separate comparisons vs. comparison with 2 expressions

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Are these two the same in big O notation?

1:

```
If False
    do something
If True
    do something
```

2:

```
If False or True
    do something
```

Comment: Yes they are both O(do something) if *do something* is the same thing in this three situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Recall that big-O notation basically gives you the computation steps up to a constant factor.  If you're counting comparisons, the first code fragment makes 2; the second computes either 1 or 2.  In either case, it's O(1) because k*1 is 1 for any constant k.

Answer (score 0):

**yes.**

In the end, either way you end up doing the thing - and they could also be replaced with simply
    `do something`.